# Partition and mount my secondary hard drive on CentOS 5.5 64bit?

Tags: centos, mount, partition

I am trying to prepare my second hard drive for user image uploads. Here is the current layout:

```
#  sudo parted /dev/sda print

Model: ATA WDC WD2500KS-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary   ext3         boot 
 2      107MB   8595MB  8488MB  primary   linux-swap        
 3      8595MB  10.7GB  2147MB  primary   ext3              
 4      10.7GB  250GB   239GB   extended                    
 5      10.7GB  250GB   239GB   logical   ext3              

Information: Don't forget to update /etc/fstab, if necessary.
```

I am assuming #4 is my secondary drive? How do I partition and mount it so I can begin using it? And how do I add to fstab? I understand if it's to many questions in one, just help me with whatever you can I guess :) Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

number 4 is not the second drive is just an extended partition so don't do anything with it !

to find your second drive run this

```
dmesg |grep sd
```

note what disks are coming up (you already have the sda so make sure you don't touch it)
probably you will have sdb and if that is the case do the following

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
n -- to add a new primary partition and choose the whole drive 
w -- to write it to the drive
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1 -- to create the file system
mount /dev/sdb1 /to_my_image_dir
```

Comment: # dmesg |grep sd
SCSI device sda: 488397168 512-byte hdwr sectors (250059 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sda: 488397168 512-byte hdwr sectors (250059 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
 sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 < sda5 >
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
EXT3 FS on sda5, internal journal
EXT3 FS on sda3, internal journal
EXT3 FS on sda1, internal journal

Comment: Adding 8289532k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:8289532k

Comment: @andrew are you certain that you have a secondary hard drive? Try `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: I paid for two HDDs, I sure hope so

Comment: # fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 892.2 GB, 892279455744 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 108480 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      108480   871365568+  83  Linux

Comment: ok then just follow from fdisk /dev/sdb

Comment: wrong box sorry, let me re run that command on correct server

Comment: Here is the output... Nothing

Comment: ok then what it could be then is they set a hard ware raid for you and you see just one drive ... call the supplier.

Comment: [root@D18634 ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[root@D18634 ~]# 
no output what so ever

Comment: fdisk /dev/sdb

Unable to open /dev/sdb
[root@D18634 ~]#

Comment: if there is no second drive into the system is not much you can do.

Comment: okay i guess i dont have a second, thank you! time to complain :)